# ArrayField custom widget similar to JSONFieldWedget

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I want to display the content of an `ArrayField` in a Django admin panel similar to how a `JSONField` is displayed using `JSONFieldWidget`

My model's array field is a bit long to use something like: [django-better-admin-arrayfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-better-admin-arrayfield/)

I will not be saving or updating anything via Django admin panel.

Comment: Please *don't* use an `ArrayField`, it violates first normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: thank you for the reply. What should I use instead?

Comment: A `ForeignKey` from an extra model, or a `ManyToManyField`.